# lineplot for different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How can I (using ggplot) plot a barplot but with lines instead of bars. Additionally I want to draw different lines for different groups, so that I can compare the frequency distributions between the groups.

Let's say I have a `df` with two variables `var1` (the variable I want to plot the frequency distribution) and `grp`.

I can do it with a barplot, but lines would seem more clear to me:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=var1, fill=grp), data=df)+
geom_bar(position='dodge')+
ylab("Var 1")+
xlab("Frequencies by group")
```

Comment: a sample of `df` would help... use `dput`. and what should `a barplot without bars but with lines` look like?

Comment: Have you tried using `geom_line` and looking at the relevant documentation? If so what is happening when you try to implement that? If not, what have you tried?

Comment: I have actually tried geom_line, but there I need to specify a y-variable which (in my case) is only the relative frequency of var1 within each group.

Comment: Oh right - I'm not sure that will make much sense as a line graph, because it implies some sort of link between the groups that might not be there, unless perhaps they are ordered factors. Regardless, you could try having `Var 1` as the y-axis and `grp` as the x-axis. You wouldn't have a line for each group, if you are saying that each bar at the moment represents a group, as each point in the line will represent a group. If that isn't what you want, can you explain what you think the line should actually be representing?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a little misunderstanding. It should look like a geom_density. But because I have 6 groups the areas are overlapping too much and it gets messy, even if I set a lower alpha-value. I just want to have the upper line (of a density plot) for each group. And var1 is a categorical variable not a continuous one, therefore the line does not have to be smooth.

Comment: Thanks! geom_freqpoly is what I was looking for :-)

Comment: You just said `var1` is categorical, so I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

A bar graph is combining a `stat` that counts with a `geom` that draws bars. To change it to lines, you can either do:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), col = factor(am), group = am))+
  geom_line(stat = 'count')
```

Or:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), col = factor(am), group = am))+
  stat_count(geom = 'line', position = 'identity')
```

[image]